# Transform FeatureCollection to a LineString with Geotools

Tags: geotools, geomesa

I am using Geomesa and I want to program something that works with JAVA , here in this exampel I am trying to fetch some points in a zone and transform it to a line to draw it later :

```
Query query=new Query(feature.getTypeName());
        query.setFilter(CQL.toFilter(filtre));
        query.setSortBy(new SortBy[] {CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory2().sort("dtg",SortOrder.ASCENDING) });
        FeatureCollection collection=source.getFeatures(query);
        FeatureIterator iterator=collection.features();
```

I got all the points I need but the problem is that I can't directly transform it to a LineString , what I did is that I iterated all the collection and collected the geometry of each element in an ArrayList after that I transformed the ArrayList into an Array of Coordinate and created the LineString

```
   Coordinate[] tab;
        cool.add(((com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point)save.getDefaultGeometry()).getCoordinate());
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            actuel=iterator.next();
            double distance= ( (com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point)save.getDefaultGeometry()).distance((com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point)actuel.getDefaultGeometry());
                if(distance<0.3 ){
                    if(distance>0) 
                   cool.add(((com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point) actuel.getDefaultGeometry()).getCoordinate());

            }
            else{
                tab=new Coordinate[cool.size()];
                tab=cool.toArray(tab);
                route=factory.createLinearRing(tab);
                System.out.println(route);
                cool=new ArrayList<>();
            }
        }
        tab=new Coordinate[cool.size()+1];
        tab=cool.toArray(tab);
        tab[cool.size()]=cool.get(0);
        route=factory.createLinearRing(tab);
        System.out.println(route);
        iterator.close();
```

Is there another Way to get all the points directly without doing all this work?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you have a `SimpleFeatureCollection` of `Point`s and you want to convert it into a `LineString` where if there is a gap of more than 0.3 (of a degree?) you start a new line.

There is no shortcut to convert a set of features to a line, so you will need to iterate through them and extract the points. This is how I would do it:

```
  public List<LineString> toLine(SimpleFeatureCollection features) {
    GeometryFactory factory = new GeometryFactory();
    Point lastPoint = null;
    List<LineString> routes = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Coordinate> coordList = new ArrayList<>();
    LineString route;
    try (SimpleFeatureIterator iter = features.features()) {
      while (iter.hasNext()) {
        SimpleFeature f = iter.next();
        Point p = (Point) f.getDefaultGeometry();
        double distance;
        if (lastPoint != null) {
          distance = p.distance(lastPoint);
        } else {
          distance = -1;
          lastPoint = p;
        }
        if (distance != -1 && distance < 0.3) {
          if (distance > 0) {
            // skip repeats
            coordList.add(p.getCoordinate());
          }
        } else {
          route = factory.createLineString(coordList.toArray(new Coordinate[] {}));
          routes.add(route);
          System.out.println(route);
          coordList = new ArrayList<>();
        }
      }
    }
    return routes;
  }
```